# Add column in which a value j of a row i is inserted

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to use a loop to print the column (variable) corresponding to certain specific values of a row (sample) in a large data frame. For example

`c1<-c(1,2,3)
c2<-c(4,5,6)
c3<-c(7,8,9)
data<-as.data.frame(rbind(c1,c2,c3))`

```
    row V1  V2  V3
    r1  1   2   3
    r2  4   5   6
    r3  7   8   9
```

If ri=j ( where j is a list of values) then I want to add to the data frame the column in which the value j of the row i is inserted. For example if the target values of the list were

for r1=2

for r2=12

for r3=7

Then the results would be

```
    row V1  V2  V3   V4  V5
    r1  1   2   3   2   1    
    r2  4   5   6   5   4
    r3  7   8   9   8   7
```

Any advice?

Comment: What do you mean with "for r1=2 for r2=12, for r3=7"?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. It is just an example, for the row 1 the value 2, for the row 2 value 12 (which does not exist in the example) and for row 3 value 7. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have a list, where each element is the values you want to match for each row:

```
r.values <- list(r1=c(2), r2=c(12), r3=c(7))
```

And your data frame as before:

```
data <- data.frame(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9))
```

Now we want to build a vector of column indices of interest based on where each row matches the values in `r.values`:

```
indices <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  indices <- c(indices, which(data[i,] %in% r.values[[i]]))
}
data[,indices]
```

This gives you the following:

```
   V2 V1
c1  2  1
c2  5  4
c3  8  7
```

The nice thing is this can be extended to look at multiple values across rows, or ignore rows entirely:

```
r.values <- list(c(2,3), NA, r3=c(7,8))
```

Running the above loop again gives you:

```
   V2 V3 V1 V2.1
c1  2  3  1    2
c2  5  6  4    5
c3  8  9  7    8
```

Comment: Thanks! This is probably the best solution for me, because of the possibility to select multiple values in particular rows in a very simple way. the solution of ferdinand.kraft seems also very elegant to me.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a vector of row indices `rows <- c(1,2,3)` and a vector of corresponding values `val <- c(2, 12, 7)`.

We start creating a vector to grab all columns that should be added:

```
newcols <- c()

for(i in seq_along(rows))
{
  temp <- which(data[rows[i],]==val[i])

  if(length(temp)==0) temp <- NA

  newcols[i] <- temp
}
```

Now we simply add your columns:

```
result <- cbind(data, data[, newcols[!is.na(newcols)]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i <- c(1, 2, 3)
j <- c(2, 12, 7)

col.idx <- mapply(match, j, split(data, rownames(data))[i])
# [1]  2 NA  1

data.frame(data, data[i, na.omit(col.idx)])
#    V1 V2 V3 V2.1 V1.1
# c1  1  2  3    2    1
# c2  4  5  6    5    4
# c3  7  8  9    8    7
```